# Given a hash of items (also a hash), return a hash that consolidates duplicates and provide counts for each item

Tags: ruby, hash, count, hash-of-hashes

I'm working to better understand hashes, and I've come across problems in which I have a collection with duplicate items and I need to return a hash of those items de-duped while adding a key that counts those items. For example...

I have a hash of grocery items and each item points to another hash that describes various attributes of each item.

```
groceries = [
    {"avocado" => {:price => 3.0, :on_sale => true}},
    {"tomato" => {:price => 1.0, :on_sale => false}},
    {"avocado" => {:price => 3.0, :on_sale => true}},
    {"kale" => {:price => 5.0, :on_sale => false}}
]
```

And I want my updated groceries to be...

```
groceries_updated = {
    "avocado" => {:price => 3.0, :on_sale => true, :count => 2},
    "tomato" => {:price => 1.0, :on_sale => false, :count => 1},
    "kale" => {:price => 5.0, :on_sale => false, :count => 1}
}
```

My initial approach was first create my new hash by iterating through the original hash so I would have something like this. Then I would iterate through the original hash again and increase the counter in my new hash. *I'm wondering if this can be done in one iteration of the hash.* I've also tried using the **#each_with_object** method, but I also need a better understanding of the parameters. My attempt with #each_with_object results in an array of hashes with the :count key added, but no consolidation.

```
def consolidate_cart(array)
  array.each do |hash|
    hash.each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = {price: nil, clearance: nil, count: 0}}) do |(item, info), obj|
      puts "#{item} -- #{info}"
      puts "#{obj[item][:count] += 1}"
      puts "#{obj}"
    end 
  end
end
```

Comment: This is a classic case for `inject`

Comment: What is `avocado` in the above code? It looks like a variable or method name (rather than, say, a Symbol or String key). If so, what does it return? Keep in mind that a Hash can only have one instance of each key, so the code `{ avocado: "foo", avocado: "bar" }` (in which `:avocado` is a duplicated Symbol key) would simply return `{ avocado: "bar" }`. Before you solve your stated problem, you're going to need to rethink your data structure.

Comment: “I've also tried using the `#each_with_object` method”—this is a lie. You could not try anything with the input you’ve provided: it’s not a valid ruby object.

Comment: Please include realistic test data. The code snippets you've provided now are *not* valid Ruby code, and the equivalent hashes would also not be usable, as hashes cannot have duplicate keys.

Comment: My mistake, I've updated my code snippets to be representative of what I was working with. Original variable was an array, which is why there are duplicates and I'm returning a hash. And my keys are strings

Comment: @user3059274 A hash cannot have duplicate keys, so you can't just change the array into a hash like that.  This question might be better if you show the input data as the arrays you have in hand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `inject` to build the consolidated groceries in the following way:

```
groceries = [
    {"avocado" => {:price => 3.0, :on_sale => true}},
    {"tomato" => {:price => 1.0, :on_sale => false}},
    {"avocado" => {:price => 3.0, :on_sale => true}},
    {"kale" => {:price => 5.0, :on_sale => false}}
]

groceries_updated = groceries.inject({}) do |consolidated, grocery|
  item = grocery.keys.first
  consolidated[item] ||= grocery[item].merge(count: 0)
  consolidated[item][:count] += 1
  consolidated
end
```

`inject` takes the initial state of the object you want to build (in this case a `{}`) and a block that will be called for each element of the array. The purpose of the block is to modify/populate the object. 
A good description on how to use `inject` can be found [here](http://blog.jayfields.com/2008/03/ruby-inject.html).

In your case, the block will either add a new item to a hash or increment its `count` if it already exists. The code above will add a new item to the hash, with a `count` of 0, only if it doesn't exist (that's what `||=` do). Then it will increment the `count`.

One thing to note is that the values in the original `groceries` array might be different (for instance, one `avocado` entry might have a `price` of 3.0, and another a `price` of 3.5). The values in `groceries_updated` will contain whichever was first in the original array.

Answer (score 0):

One-liner (almost, just split in some chained blocks):

```
groceries.
  group_by { |h| h.keys.first }.
  transform_values { |v| v.first.values.first.merge(count: v.size) }
```

Explanation:

First block splits the list into several values based on the (supposed single) hash key:

```
{
  "avocado" => [
    {"avocado" => {:price => 3.0, :on_sale => true}},
    {"avocado" => {:price => 3.0, :on_sale => true}}
  ],
  "tomato" => [
    {"tomato" => {:price => 1.0, :on_sale => false}}
  ], ...
}
```

The second block takes one value

```
[
  {"avocado" => {:price => 3.0, :on_sale => true}},
  {"avocado" => {:price => 3.0, :on_sale => true}}
]
```

reads the supposedly single value of the first item, and merges with the total count.

:tada: